# How to check if a process is running inside docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, containers

[Updated1] I have a shell which will change TCP kernel parameters in some functions, but now I need to make this shell run in Docker container, that means, the shell need to know it is running inside a container and stop configuring the kernel.

Now I'm not sure how to achieve that, here is the contents of `/proc/self/cgroup` inside the container:

```
9:hugetlb:/
8:perf_event:/
7:blkio:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct:/
2:cpu:/docker/25ef774c390558ad8c4e9a8590b6a1956231aae404d6a7aba4dde320ff569b8b
1:cpuset:/
```

Any flags above can I use to figure out if this process is running inside a container?

[Updated2]: I have also noticed [Determining if a process runs inside lxc/Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/determining-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker), but it seems not working in this case, the content in `/proc/1/cgroup` of my container is:

```
8:perf_event:/
7:blkio:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpuacct:/
2:cpu:/docker/25ef774c390558ad8c4e9a8590b6a1956231aae404d6a7aba4dde320ff569b8b
1:cpuset:/
```

No /lxc/containerid

Comment: Not a very clear question.  Why do you need this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/determining-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker

Comment: @fish no /lxc/<containerid> in my case, see update

Comment: @HenkLangeveld kernel parameters is read-only in Docker container,so I need to know if my shell is running inside containers and disable kernel functions in my shell. see update.

Comment: Some steps in the script try to modify kernel parameters, and need to be skipped when running in Docker.  Clear.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To check inside a Docker container if you are inside a Docker container or not can be done via `/proc/1/cgroup`. As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/determining-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker) suggests you can to the following:

Outside a docker container all entries in `/proc/1/cgroup` end on `/` as you can see here:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-13:~$ cat /proc/1/cgroup
11:name=systemd:/
10:hugetlb:/
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:freezer:/
6:devices:/
5:memory:/
4:cpuacct:/
3:cpu:/
2:cpuset:/
```

Inside a Docker container some of the control groups will belong to Docker (or LXC):

```
vagrant@ubuntu-13:~$ docker run busybox cat /proc/1/cgroup
11:name=systemd:/
10:hugetlb:/
9:perf_event:/
8:blkio:/
7:freezer:/
6:devices:/docker/3601745b3bd54d9780436faa5f0e4f72bb46231663bb99a6bb892764917832c2
5:memory:/
4:cpuacct:/
3:cpu:/docker/3601745b3bd54d9780436faa5f0e4f72bb46231663bb99a6bb892764917832c2
2:cpuset:/
```

Comment: it is not strictly true that "Outside a docker container all entries in /proc/1/cgroup end on /". On ubuntu 16.04 for example I have: `12:perf_event:/
11:blkio:/init.scope
10:cpuset:/
9:devices:/init.scope
8:hugetlb:/
7:cpu,cpuacct:/init.scope
6:net_cls,net_prio:/
5:memory:/init.scope
4:pids:/init.scope
3:rdma:/
2:freezer:/
1:name=systemd:/init.scope
`

Comment: This pretty much only works on Linux, not on Darwin or other BSDs that don't even use a procfs.

Comment: @Christian Docker/LXC are Linux only things, so that's fine, right :)?

Comment: @RobertLacroix so you're saying if you don't find a procfs, you're not in Docker? Well, that's fair enough I guess...

Comment: pid 1 won't work when container is being started with host's pid namespace ( `docker run --pid=host`) thus `/proc/self/cgroups` or `/proc/$$/cgroups` is better i suppose.

Comment: `cat /proc/1/cgroup` merely outputs `0::/` while in a Docker container. Can anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: @ipid are you trying from inside a Docker container on a macOS host?  Because I see the same thing inside containers running on a macOS host.  Checking for the existence of `/.dockerenv` works on macOS, though.

Comment: As [stated here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/is-process-running-inside-container), you might also want to try:
`cat /proc/self/mountinfo`

If it works, that’s because it’s using control group v2, instead of v1 (which uses /proc/1/cgroup).

Comment: This does not work for me, running a debian container on ubuntu 22.04. `/proc/self/cgroup` and `at /proc/1/cgroup` only contain `0::/`

Answer (score 191):

Docker creates `.dockerenv` and <strike>`.dockerinit`</strike> ([removed in v1.11](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19490)) files at the top of the container's directory tree so you might want to check if those exist.

Something like this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /.dockerenv ]; then
    echo "I'm inside matrix ;(";
else
    echo "I'm living in real world!";
fi
```

Comment: Unless, of course, you or someone else has created `/.dockerinit` on your host (perhaps by accident), in which case it will be wrong outside a container.

Comment: If somebody else made it in / then they are root and you've got worse problems than knowing whether you are in docker or no.

Comment: Beware relying on `/.dockerenv` in the long term. It is [not intended to be used this way](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18355#issuecomment-220484748).

Comment: fwiw, Podman does not create `/.dockerenv`.  It does create `/run/.containerenv` but by similar logic, sounds like implementation detail not to be relied upon.  See https://github.com/containers/libpod/issues/3586 for some podman-specific alternatives.

Comment: just an alternative way of writing the above test `test -f /.dockerenv && echo inside docker || echo not inside docker`

Comment: Does this work in windows container?

Comment: @cowlinator Windows containers are even easier, just check `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ContainerType`, any value means you're in a Windows container.

Comment: Can't find it in the docker docs!?!

Answer (score 40):

We use the proc's sched (/proc/$PID/sched) to extract the PID of the process. The process's PID inside the container will differ then it's PID on the host (a non-container system).

For example, the output of /proc/1/sched on a container
will return:

```
root@33044d65037c:~# cat /proc/1/sched | head -n 1
bash (5276, #threads: 1)
```

While on a non-container host:

```
$ cat /proc/1/sched  | head -n 1
init (1, #threads: 1)
```

This helps to differentiate if you are in a container or not.  eg you can do:

```
if [[ ! $(cat /proc/1/sched | head -n 1 | grep init) ]]; then {
    echo in docker
} else {
    echo not in docker
} fi
```

Comment: this is actually quite a valuable information. thanks

Comment: Depending on the OS, "init" might need to be replaced with "systemd". More information on systemd [here](https://www.tecmint.com/systemd-replaces-init-in-linux/).

Comment: As mentioned by @BrianV, this doesn't work for me too.

Comment: In a Docker container running on a k8s cluster, `head -n1 /proc/1/sched` returns `dumb-init (1, #threads: 1)`, so the check suggested in this answer fails. (Also, contrary to what the answer suggests, the PID is shown as "1" in that line although I'm doing this in a container.)

Comment: This is definitely not a universal solution.  You can (sort of) use whatever you want for a container's PID 1.  E.g. if you do `docker run --init ...` it will be `docker-init`.  If you do e.g. `docker run ... head -n 1 /proc/1/sched` it will be `head`.

Comment: This method is not durable.

Comment: Here's a shorter version and without violating any [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) rules: `EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(if head -n 1 /proc/1/sched | grep -q 'tini'; then echo "docker run [name of this container]"; else echo "${0}"; fi)`.
This assumes that you're using [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) in your container, of course.

Comment: This answer is the only one that still works for Docker v20. 


Simplest code to wrap it (exit code 0 if  running with different _init_ than systemd or init: 

`awk '{exit ($1 ~ /^init|systemd$/)}' /proc/1/sched`

Comment: Instead of `cat /proc/1/sched | head -n 1` you can simply use `head -n 1 /proc/1/sched`.

Comment: Note that this does not appear to work any longer. At least on ubuntu Jammy (kernel 5.15.0 and docker 20.10.12) the pid in the top line of /proc/nnn/sched is now the PID from inside the container when viewed in the container.

Answer (score 38):

## Using Environment Variables

For my money, I prefer to set an **environment variable** inside the docker image that can then be detected by the application.

For example, this is the start of a demo `Dockerfile` config:

```
FROM node:12.20.1 as base
ENV DOCKER_RUNNING=true
RUN yarn install --production
RUN yarn build
```

The second line sets an envar called `DOCKER_RUNNING` that is then easy to detect.  The issue with this is that in a multi-stage build, you will have to repeat the `ENV` line every time you `FROM` off of an external image.  For example, you can see that I `FROM` off of `node:12.20.1`, which includes a lot of extra stuff (git, for example).  Later on in my `Dockerfile` I then `COPY` things over to a new image based on `node:12.20.1-slim`, which is much smaller:

```
FROM node:12.20.1-slim as server
ENV DOCKER_RUNNING=true
EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=base /build /build
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Even though this image target `server` is in the same `Dockerfile`, it requires the ENV var to be defined again because it has a different base image.

If you make use of Docker-Compose, you could instead easily define an envar there.  For example, your `docker-compose.yml` file could look like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nodeserver:
    image: michaeloryl/stackdemo
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DOCKER_RUNNING=true
```

Comment: This is great, just being explicit

Comment: Beware that some programs do purge environment when starting (e.g shiny server).  The variables are there if you open a shell, but empty within the program.  In that case check out how to configure those vars for that particular software.

Answer (score 23):

Thomas' solution as code:

```
running_in_docker() {
  (awk -F/ '$2 == "docker"' /proc/self/cgroup | read non_empty_input)
}
```

---

Note

The `read` with a dummy variable is a simple idiom for *Does this produce any output?*. It's a compact method for turning a possibly verbose `grep` or `awk` into a *test* of a pattern.

[Additional note on read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513045/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-inside-docker-container/23575107?noredirect=1#comment53780774_23575107)

Comment: Except...this will fail in some envrionments, because, e.g., `3:cpu,cpuacct:/system.slice/docker-1ce79a0dec4a2084d54acf187a1e177e0339dc90d0218b48b4456576ecaf291e.scope` would not match.  Simpler to `grep -q docker /proc/1/cgroup`; the result code from that should also be sufficient.

Comment: `read` might work for `bash`, but in the most used `dash` shell you have to use either `read dummy` (or similar) or use a construct like `[ -n "$(command)" ]`

Comment: @DanielAlder Good catch, Daniel.  I will update the text.

Comment: Previously this claimed that any Bourne compatible shell supports the plain `read` without variable name. This is only true for bash and ksh93.  The Opengroup only specifies `read var` and does not mention `read` behaviour without at least one variable.  In _bash_ and _ksh93_, if no _var_ is given, read uses the shell variable `REPLY`.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld This would fix your solution:
(awk -F: '$3 ~ /docker/' /proc/self/cgroup | read non_empty_input)

Comment: Why can't we just use `awk -F: '$3 ~ /docker/' /proc/self/cgroup | read`? Works for me.

Comment: @larsks Indeed, `grep` is simpler. However, using `-q` didn't work on my docker container (command returned nothing) so it's better to omit it.

Comment: @frakman1 the `grep -q` command is not expected to return anything. See the `grep(1)` man page.

Answer (score 17):

What works for me is to check for the inode number of the '/.' 
Inside the docker, its a very high number.
Outside the docker, its a very low number like '2'.
I reckon this approach would also depend on the FileSystem being used.

Example

## Inside the docker:

```
# ls -ali / | sed '2!d' |awk {'print $1'}
1565265
```

## Outside the docker

```
$ ls -ali / | sed '2!d' |awk {'print $1'}
2
```

In a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INODE_NUM=`ls -ali / | sed '2!d' |awk {'print $1'}`
if [ $INODE_NUM == '2' ];
then
        echo "Outside the docker"
else
        echo "Inside the docker"
fi
```

Comment: in MSYS2  ls -ali / | sed '2!d' |awk {'print $1'} 232779805740174872

Comment: same as  `ls -di /` ? seems inode num not reliable on different platform

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me to differentiate between a Xen domU host and its docker container

Comment: `stat -c %i` is simpler than `ls -ali / | sed '2!d' |awk {'print $1'}`

Comment: Being inside a `chroot` returns a different inode number for '/' too but that does not mean I am inside a container

Answer (score 4):

Based on Dan Walsh's [comment](https://github.com/containers/libpod/issues/3586#issuecomment-512242478) about using SELinux `ps -eZ | grep container_t`, but without requiring `ps` to be installed:

```sh
$ podman run --rm fedora:31 cat /proc/1/attr/current
system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c56,c299
$ podman run --rm alpine cat /proc/1/attr/current
system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c558,c813
$ docker run --rm fedora:31 cat /proc/1/attr/current
system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c8,c583
$ cat /proc/1/attr/current
system_u:system_r:init_t:s0
```

This just tells you you're running in *a* container, but not which runtime.

Didn't check other container runtimes but https://opensource.com/article/18/2/understanding-selinux-labels-container-runtimes provides more info and suggests this is widely used, *might* also work for rkt and lxc?

Answer (score 4):

golang code, via the /proc/%s/cgroup to check a process in a docker,include the k8s cluster

```
func GetContainerID(pid int32) string {
    cgroupPath := fmt.Sprintf("/proc/%s/cgroup", strconv.Itoa(int(pid)))
    return getContainerID(cgroupPath)
}

func GetImage(containerId string) string {
    if containerId == "" {
        return ""
    }
    image, ok := containerImage[containerId]
    if ok {
        return image
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
func getContainerID(cgroupPath string) string {
    containerID := ""
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(cgroupPath)
    if err != nil {
        return containerID
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(content), "\n")
    for _, line := range lines {
        field := strings.Split(line, ":")
        if len(field) < 3 {
            continue
        }
        cgroup_path := field[2]
        if len(cgroup_path) < 64 {
            continue
        }
        // Non-systemd Docker
        //5:net_prio,net_cls:/docker/de630f22746b9c06c412858f26ca286c6cdfed086d3b302998aa403d9dcedc42
        //3:net_cls:/kubepods/burstable/pod5f399c1a-f9fc-11e8-bf65-246e9659ebfc/9170559b8aadd07d99978d9460cf8d1c71552f3c64fefc7e9906ab3fb7e18f69
        pos := strings.LastIndex(cgroup_path, "/")
        if pos > 0 {
            id_len := len(cgroup_path) - pos - 1
            if id_len == 64 {
                //p.InDocker = true
                // docker id
                containerID = cgroup_path[pos+1 : pos+1+64]
                // logs.Debug("pid:%v in docker id:%v", pid, id)
                return containerID
            }
        }
        // systemd Docker
        //5:net_cls:/system.slice/docker-afd862d2ed48ef5dc0ce8f1863e4475894e331098c9a512789233ca9ca06fc62.scope
        docker_str := "docker-"
        pos = strings.Index(cgroup_path, docker_str)
        if pos > 0 {
            pos_scope := strings.Index(cgroup_path, ".scope")
            id_len := pos_scope - pos - len(docker_str)
            if pos_scope > 0 && id_len == 64 {
                containerID = cgroup_path[pos+len(docker_str) : pos+len(docker_str)+64]
                return containerID
            }
        }
    }
    return containerID
}
```

Comment: care to explain what the code does? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We needed to exclude processes running in containers, but instead of checking for just docker cgroups we decided to compare `/proc/<pid>/ns/pid` to the init system at `/proc/1/ns/pid`. Example:

```
pid=$(ps ax | grep "[r]edis-server \*:6379" | awk '{print $1}')
if [ $(readlink "/proc/$pid/ns/pid") == $(readlink /proc/1/ns/pid) ]; then
   echo "pid $pid is the same namespace as init system"
else
   echo "pid $pid is in a different namespace as init system"
fi
```

Or in our case we wanted a one liner that generates an error if the process is NOT in a container

```
bash -c "test -h /proc/4129/ns/pid && test $(readlink /proc/4129/ns/pid) != $(readlink /proc/1/ns/pid)"
```

which we can execute from another process and if the exit code is zero then the specified PID is running in a different namespace.

Comment: Does not work for me. From within a k8s-scheduled Docker container, `readlink /proc/self/ns/pid` and `readlink /proc/1/ns/pid` produce the same output.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Might want to try using https://github.com/jessfraz/amicontained to see what features are enabled in the container runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Process with pid 1 will be different between container and host:

- On Linux host systems it will be systemd or init
- In Docker container it will be the process that is run by the container,
  but not systemd or init

Check process name with pid 1

```
$ ps -p 1 -o comm=
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, as long as I know the system programs/scrips will be running on, is confirming if what's running with *PID 1*  is `systemd` (or equivalent). If not, that's a container.
And this should be true for any linux container, not only docker.

Answer (score 0):

The `/.dockerenv` file seems to not exist when using GitPod, so I used the following check extra to @at0S's answer:

```bash
if [ -f /.dockerenv ] | [ -n "$(env | grep "^GITPOD")" ]; then
  echo "In Docker"
else
  echo "Outside Docker"
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Had the need for this capability in 2022 on macOS and only [the answer by @at0S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518538/1161484) still works from all the other options.

- `/proc/1/cgroup` only has the root directory in a container unless configured otherwise
- `/proc/1/sched` showed the same in-container process number. The name was different (`bash`) but that's not very portable.
- Environment variables work if you configure your container yourself, but none of the default environment variables helped

I did find an option not listed in the other answers: `/proc/1/mounts` included an `overlay` filesystem with "docker" in its path.