# use shell script to detect inside docker container

Tags: shell, docker

If use `docker run -t -i --env IN_DOCKER=1 --name cc centos /bin/bash` to enter docker container. We could check it by `IN_DOCKER` variable.

If use `docker exec -t -i cc /bin/bash` to enter the same container, `IN_DOCKER` variable works, too.

If I run `sshd` inside the container, and use ssh to login the container.
I can not found proper way to detect, it is inside a docker container.

Comment: Have you seen [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513045/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-inside-docker-container)

Comment: what's your question ? what do you want to achieve ? ssh login goes to another shell environment