# Reliable way of getting the full container name inside a container running in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Background: I have a setup where many different scalable services connect to their databases via a connection pool (per instance). These services run within a Docker Swarm.

In my current database setup, this ends up looking as follows (using PostgreSQL in this example):

```
PID | Database | User | Application                     | Client | ...
... | db1      | app  | --standard JDBC driver string-- | x      | ...
... | db1      | app  | --standard JDBC driver string-- | y      | ... 
... | db1      | app  | --standard JDBC driver string-- | y      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                             | x      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                             | x      | ... 
... | db2      | app  | --standard JDBC driver string-- | y      | ... 
... | db2      | app  | --standard JDBC driver string-- | y      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                             | x      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                             | x      | ...
```

What I would like to do, effectively, is provide the *current Docker Swarm container name, **including scaling identifier***, to the DBMS to be able to better monitor the database connections, i.e.:

```
PID | Database | User | Application        | Client | ...
... | db1      | app  | books-service.1    | x      | ...
... | db1      | app  | books-service.2    | y      | ... 
... | db1      | app  | books-service.3    | y      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                | x      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                | x      | ... 
... | db2      | app  | checkout-service.2 | y      | ... 
... | db2      | app  | checkout-service.2 | y      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                | x      | ... 
... | ...      | app  | ...                | x      | ...
```

(obviously, setting the connection string is trivial - it's getting the information to set that is the issue)

Since my applications are managed by Docker Swarm (and sometime in the future, likely Kubernetes), I cannot manually set this value via environment (as I do not perform a `docker run`).

When running `docker ps` on a given Swarm node, I see the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                 NAMES
59cdbf724091        my-docker-registry.net/books-service:latest         "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bi…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                                              books-service.1.zabvo1jal0h2xya9qfftnrnej
0eeeee15e92a        my-docker-registry.net/checkout-service:latest      "/bin/sh -c 'exec /u…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                                              checkout-service.2.189s7d09m0q86y7fdf3wpy0vc
```

Of note is the `NAMES` column, which includes an identifier for the actual *instance* of the given container (or image, however you'd prefer to look at it). Do note that this name is *not* the hostname of the container, which by default is the container ID.

I know there are ways to determine if an application is running inside Docker (e.g. [using /proc/1/cgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580008/how-does-java-application-know-it-is-running-within-a-docker-container/52581380)), but that doesn't help me either as those also only list the container ID.

Is there a way to get this value from inside a Docker container that is being run in a swarm?

Comment: Correct me if I got it wrong, you want to get `books-service.1.zabvo1jal0h2xya9qfftnrnej` from inside the container, right? Or just part of the name?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. More specifically, I want to get that value so that I can extract the `books-service.1` part. If there is a way of getting `books-service.1` directly, that would be fine too. If there is a way to get the `1` by itself, *that* would be fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need (`books-service.1`) is a combination of a swarm service name and a task slot. Both of these can be passed to the container as environment variables, as well as a full task name (`books-service.1.zabvo1jal0h2xya9qfftnrnej`):

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster
    command: cat /dev/stdout
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: '{{ .Service.Name }}'
      TASK_SLOT: '{{ .Task.Slot }}'
      TASK_NAME: "{{ .Task.Name }}"
```

After passing these you can either strip the `TASK_NAME` to get what you need or combine the `SERVICE_NAME` with the `TASK_SLOT`. Come to think of it, you can combine them right in the template:

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  test:
    image: debian:buster
    command: cat /dev/stdout
    environment:
      MY_NAME: '{{ .Service.Name }}.{{.Task.Slot}}'
```

Other possible placeholders can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#create-services-using-templates).

Comment: *Exactly* what I needed - although `task` is mentioned in the docs, I wasn't quite able to make the connection. Happy to give you the bounty as soon as it is eligible. Cheers!

Comment: On a separate note, I do wish that the last column in `docker ps` was called `TASK NAMES` instead. That would've saved me quite a bit of time. :)

Comment: @user991710 to tell the truth I had somewhat the same problem with the TASK_SLOT. I had to test experimentally to check if it is what I think it is.

Comment: There is a 1:1 binding between a task and a container. `docker ps` provides a container view, in case of swarm services it shows the container created by a task.The task names are shown by `docker service ps ${servicename}` in the NAME column.