# Am I running on container or not?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, operating-system, jelastic

Some cloud provider give us preconfigure application. I have CLI and can run command. I want to know is it container or OS(ubuntu,redhat, ...)?If it is container what is its base image?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513045/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-inside-docker-container

Answer (score 3):

#### TLDR

if you are inside a container, you will see a `.dockerenv` file on the root.
(thats why i suspect google cloud shell to be one).

to determine the os you can run `cat /etc/os-release`;

#### Edit

> if it is container what is its base image?

It seems like this thing varies from cloud provider to another, so you will have to do the digging yourself every time.

I've just done mine, here are the results:

#### exploring google cloudshell base image:

- I did `cat /etc/hostname` to get the container id, and got this:

  ```
    cs-6000-devshell-vm-41dc38ac-9af5-42e2-9ee5-b6f9d042decb
  ```

  which may provide a clue about some source `devshell` image
- so I went for a Dockerfile: `sudo find / -type f -name Dockerfile`

and one of the results was:

```
/google/devshell/customimageskeleton/Dockerfile
```

which looked quite appropriate to me. so i `cat /google/devshell/customimageskeleton/Dockerfile`

and got

```
FROM gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest
# Add your content here
# To trigger a rebuild of your Cloud Shell image:
# 1. Commit your changes locally: git commit -a
# 2. Push your changes upstream: git push origin master
# This triggers a rebuild of your image hosted at GCR_REPO_URL.
# You can find the Cloud Source Repository hosting this file at CSR_FILE_URL
```

A quick googling on the `gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest` led me right into [the image repo in google cloud registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloudshell-images/GLOBAL/cloudshell@sha256:988004a370d465d3ca1217639d8e81684d0bf18a15572a7a0eb19bcdefeabc38/details?tab=info)

As you can see there, the image size is quite huge so i couldnt pull it anywhere, but if that bothers you, you can

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest
```

and then

```
docker history --no-trunc gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest
```

to view the base `Dockerfile`.

Hope that can help somebody somehow.

Comment: you do well. but I do not use google cloud in kubernetes this command   find / -type f -name Dockerfile   does not work

Comment: so where are you? its going to be a different research in each cloud provider. if you cant find any docs, try to find clues inside the container, such as the container id and any dockerfiles inside it.

Answer (score 1):

All containers certified by Jelastic are based on Centos OS v.7, with the exception of the image with Ubuntu VPS. In order to check the version Linux OS, you need to run commands:

For example:

**for containers based on Centos OS:**

**$ cat /etc/os-release**

NAME="CentOS Linux"

VERSION="7 (Core)"

ID="centos"

ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"

VERSION_ID="7"

PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

ANSI_COLOR="0;31"

CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"

HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

---

**for containers based on Debian OS:**

**# cat /etc/os-release**

NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"

VERSION_ID="18.04"

HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"

SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-
policy"

VERSION_CODENAME=bionic

UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

**# lsb_release -a**

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID:Ubuntu

Description:Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Release:18.04

Codename:bionic

Comment: When I buy python. Is it container or CentOS that python is install on it?

Comment: Please read once again: "All containers certified by Jelastic (incl. Python) are based on Centos OS v.7, with the exception of the image with Ubuntu VPS."

Comment: it means it is not container?or the base image of container is CentOS?

Comment: If it is container How jelastic can mount the root?!

Comment: Almost every time It is a container based on CentOS.