# is there a way to know if jenkins is running inside a container or not?

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I want to write a pipeline that can starts a build in jenkins docker container and i can use the same pipeline to start the same build on a jenkins server (i mean ordinary server without docker). thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a process is running inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513045/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-inside-docker-container)

Comment: Way to check if jenkins service is up or not is systemctl status jenkins