# Detect if running in Windows container

Tags: windows, docker

I'm developing an application that has to run in both Linux and Windows based containers. I know that when I run a Linux container in Docker - a file /.dockerenv gets created inside the container. Therefore, your application can detect whether it is running in a Docker container via a simple check if that file exists or not. However, I've recently downloaded Docker for Windows and started playing with Windows-based containers. So, I've created a simple Docker file and started a container from it (followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile). I thought that the same file would be created in the FS root (e.g. C:\.dockerenv), but there is no such. So, has anyone experienced this before? How can I detect if my app is running in a Windows based container? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To be certain you're in a container, you could set an environment variable in your Dockerfile.

```
FROM ...
ENV INSIDE_DOCKER_CONTAINER=true
RUN ...
```

Then you could check from your application if that environment variable is set. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65942222/6105431

To know what operating system the container is, it would probably help to know what programming language your application is written in. Many cross-platform languages can detect the OS.

If you're writing a .NET C#, for example, you can check using the RuntimeInformation class.

```csharp
RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);
```

Alternatively, your Dockerfile could also simply set *another* environment variable.

```
FROM ...
ENV INSIDE_DOCKER_CONTAINER=true
ENV CONTAINER_OS=windows
RUN ...
```