# How to determine whether a process is running in a container or not (in linux)?

Tags: c, linux, docker, linux-kernel, containers

I am trying to determine whether a process is running in a container or not? Is there any method to see from the point of host view? Is there any method to check it by using linux kernel namespace?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513045/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-inside-docker-container

Comment: Also `ps afx` gives a lot of information w.r.t processes and its parents, you can find the processes started by `lxc-start`