# Model with no controller issue with passing parameters while creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I created a model called `exam_questions` (I didn't create a specific controller for it) and I tried to create multiple records at once with:

form:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "basic_methods", :action => "create_exam_questions"}, method: :post) do %>
 <% (1..exam.number_of_questions).each do |question_number| %>
 <div class="panel panel-default panel-question">
  <div clas="panel-header" style="background-color: white;color:black;padding:15px;">
      <h2>Question <%= question_number %>:</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:25px;">       
   <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_question_no, question_number, :name => "exam_questions[][question_no]" %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_question_type, 1, :name => "exam_questions[][question_type]" %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_question_exam_id, exam.id, :name => "exam_questions[][exam_id]" %>
   <%= text_area_tag :exam_question_text, '', :placeholder => "Question....", class:"form-control", :name => "exam_questions[][question]", :rows => 10%>
   <br />
   <br />
   <h3>Options seperated by a comma (e.g Mycobacterium Bovis,Mycobacterium Tuberclosis,Plasmodium Falciparum,Plasmodium vivax):</h3>
   <%= text_field_tag :exam_question_exam_options, '', class:"form-control", :placeholder => "Options seperated by a comma e.g Mycobacterium Bovis,Mycobacterium Tuberclosis,Plasmodium Falciparum,Plasmodium vivax", :name => "exam_questions[][exam_options]"%>
   <br />
   <h3>Correct answers (option seperated by comma e.g A,B,C,D) or (single option e.g A) :</h3>
   <%= text_field_tag :exam_question_correct_answers, '', class:"form-control", :placeholder => "Correct answer option seperated by comma e.g A,B,C,D", :name => "exam_questions[][correct_answers]"%>
   <br />
   <br />
  </div>
 </div> 
 <% end %>
 <div class="text-center">
 <%= submit_tag "Create Exam", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

controller(basic_methods_controller) method:

```
params[:exam_questions].each do |exam_question_params|
      parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(exam_question_params)
      @exam_question = ExamQuestion.new(parameters.permit(:question, :correct_answers, :question_no, :exam_options, :question_type, :exam_id))
      @exam_question.save
end
```

console:

```
Started POST "/create_exam_questions" for *******(#IP hidden by me) at 2018-07-07 09:54:21 +0000
Cannot render console from *******(#IP hidden by me)! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/basic_methods_controller.rb:358: warning: key :name is duplicated and overwritten on line 358
Processing by BasicMethodsController#create_exam_questions as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jTlqIpR8JeoX0quDSvmU+aCaT8aw3wGgopCczTo8zkQQrNX55TXj0IJsHtkDK0SISQNEqRj08Ekk6o4SR1pu3A==", "exam_questions"=>[{"question_no"=>"1", "question_type"=>"1", "exam_id"=>"7", "question"=>"If 5x plus 32 equals 4 minus 2x what is the value of x ?", "exam_options"=>"-4,-3,4,17,12", "correct_answers"=>"A"}, {"question_no"=>"2", "question_type"=>"1", "exam_id"=>"7", "question"=>"Which of the following numbers is farthest from the number 1 on the number line?", "exam_options"=>"-10,-5,0,5,10", "correct_answers"=>"A"}], "commit"=>"Create Exam"}
  Teacher Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "teachers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "exam_questions" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-07-07 09:54:21.732397"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-07 09:54:21.732397"]]
   (19.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "exam_questions" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-07-07 09:54:21.761920"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-07 09:54:21.761920"]]
   (25.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to *******(#(root_path) hidden by me)
Completed 302 Found in 83ms (ActiveRecord: 47.3ms)
```

but it always creates records with all attributes set to nil
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code seems it should work to me, you can put a raise Exception before @exam_question.save and check all the variables and objects from console to see whats wrong.

Comment: There's so much going on here it's hard to narrow down the issue. Please post the log output from your terminal when you submit the form...starting with `Started POST`. Please edit your original question and don't post it to the comments.

Comment: @MarkMerritt Done

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up params in a rather unconventional way.

I recommend changing to something a little more conventional:

*NOTE:* ActiveRecord's `create` method can accept array params. The benefit of doing it this way: there is a single database transaction. If one of the records fails they will all fail.

For example:

```
# controller

  def create
    ExamQuestion.create(exam_question_params)
  end 

  private 

  def exam_question_params
    params.permit(exam_questions: [:question, :correct_answers, :question_no, :exam_options, :question_type, :exam_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your exact code in my dummy app and it works!
Look at the console output:

```
Started POST "/create_exam_questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-07 17:29:39 +0200
Processing by BasicMethodsController#create_exam_questions as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"p+i+8cvH642MbRgLb21CL8Y+yXmE51uKdKC7UgQg1VU=", "exam_questions"=>[{"question_no"=>"1", "question_type"=>"1", "exam_id"=>"4", "question"=>"Question text", "exam_options"=>"Exam options fill", "correct_answers"=>"C"}, {"question_no"=>"2", "question_type"=>"1", "exam_id"=>"4", "question"=>"Question text", "exam_options"=>"Exam options fill", "correct_answers"=>"C"}], "commit"=>"Create Exam"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "exam_questions" ("correct_answers", "created_at", "exam_id", "exam_options", "question", "question_no", "question_type", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["correct_answers", "C"], ["created_at", "2018-07-07 15:29:39.233939"], ["exam_id", 4], ["exam_options", "Exam options fill"], ["question", "Question text"], ["question_no", 1], ["question_type", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-07-07 15:29:39.233939"]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
```

Try with `@exam_question = ExamQuestion.new(parameters.permit!)`.

#### From console messages, try also:

- **Whitelist the IP:** [How to disable "Cannot Render Console from..." on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417328/how-to-disable-cannot-render-console-from-on-rails)
- **Controller line 358:** `basic_methods_controller.rb:358: warning: key :name is duplicated and overwritten on line 358`
- **Teacher model:** `Teacher Load (0.4ms)...` before the transaction starts, what's this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I deleted the whole model and ran a scaffold generator generating the controller and model for exam_questions.
I used the same code that I posted in the question and it worked. There must be something wrong with my generators or something