# Cannot connect to Rails server on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

When I starts rails server and connect via internet as below, I getting an error. Please Let me know what I need to do fix that.

[image]

> Started GET "/" for 183.91.0.68 at 2018-11-15 14:17:28 +0700 Cannot
>   render console from 183.91.0.68! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,
>   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
>     (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
>    Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
>    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to
>   localhost:7557 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port
>   7557)):    app/controllers/home_controller.rb:17:in `block (6 levels)
>   in index'

Comment: What's in `app/controllers/home_controller.rb`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable "Cannot Render Console from..." on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417328/how-to-disable-cannot-render-console-from-on-rails)

Comment: content in "app/controllers/home_controller.rb" as below, pls  let me know what i need to do fix that. Many thanks !

Comment: class HomeController < ApplicationController
  require 'util'

  def index
    can?(:read, 'home') do
      @graphs = Rails.cache.fetch('graphs', :expires_in => 60.seconds) do
        require 'net/http'
        require 'thread'

Comment: threads = []
        graphs = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('config/graphs.json.erb'))).result)
        for group_name, group_graphs in graphs
          for graph_name, graph in group_graphs
            for slice in graph
              threads << Thread.new(slice) do |slice|
                http = create_api_conn()
                res = http.head("/devices/?query=#{CGI::escape ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(slice['query'])}")

Comment: slice['data'] = res['Total'].to_i
                slice['href'] = url_for(controller: 'devices', action: 'index', params: {query: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(slice['query'])}, only_path: true)
                slice.delete('query')
              end
            end
          end
        end
        threads.each(&:join)
        next graphs
      end
    end
  end
end

Comment: i can't attach file, pls click "edit" to view content. Thanks you !

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the possibly duplicate answer?