# Is there any way, from inside a Java program, to detect if its running in a Docker?

Tags: java, docker

Title says it.  I'm running a Java program, and from within the program I'd like to detect whether its running inside a Docker container or not.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like one of those JVM meta-issues to me. How would a Java program know if it's running in some other box? I dunno much about docker, what is docker ??

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Determining if a process runs inside Docker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20010199/697630)

Comment: I'd consider setting (or not setting) an environment variable to distinguish between environments. https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/how-should-i-get-application-configuration-into-my-docker-containers/ if you're not actually interested in docker vs not docker but in different configurations.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: To add on top of Mykola Gurov's question: isn't the whole purpose of virtualisation to not make the processes inside being aware of it? ;-)
The link in @EdwinDalorzo's comment is the answer to your question, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a process runs inside lxc/Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/how-to-determine-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker)

Answer (score 4):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518345/4222206

```
public boolean isDockerized() {
    File f = new File("/.dockerenv");
    return f.exists();
}
```