# Determining if a process runs inside windows/iis

Tags: windows, bash, docker

Is there a way to programatically / using bash scripts to identify that we are running inside a Windows based Docker Container (namely, microsoft/iis)?

Comment: I don't know what reason is behind this question, but maybe when You run container just pass this info as env? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: I am creating a tool that will run inside of people's container (which I don't control) and I need to know if my application will be running inside a Docker Container to perform my operations, that's the reason.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between "Docker" and "not Docker" or do you want to distinguish between "Windows Docker" and "non-Windows Docker"?

Comment: Distribution would be platform independent, so not a different app for both platforms.

Comment: I'd like something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/determining-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker