# While return si_addr with offset from sigwaitinfo function causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, signals

I am working on the `signal handler` to deal with reap signals, randomly I am getting the signal with offset when I call `sigwaitinfo` function. All the signal attributes are right, except for `info.si_addr`. This offset in `info.si_addr` is causing a segmentation fault.

This offset seems to be the same - I have tried removing the offset and that works, but I need a correct solution to go forward.

```
static void *signalHandler(void *vptr_args __attribute__((unused)))
  {
      sigset_t signal_set;
      siginfo_t info;

      sigemptyset(&signal_set);
      sigaddset(&signal_set, SIG_REAP);
      sigaddset(&signal_set, SIG_ISOC_CANCEL);
      sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGTERM);
      sigaddset(&signal_set, SIGPIPE);

      while (true) {
          int rc = sigwaitinfo(&signal_set, &info);
          //...
          if (rc > 0) 
{
            if(info.si_signo == SIG_REAP) 
               {
                 // Reap URBs after some simple checks
                 if ((info.si_code != SI_ASYNCIO) &&
                     (info.si_code != SI_KERNEL)) {
                      printf("Bad si_code %d in SIG_REAP", info.si_code);                      
                      continue;
                 } 
                   else {
                      printf("OK si_code %d in SIG_REAP", info.si_code);
                 }
                   struct usbdevfs_urb *ioctl_urb = (struct usbdevfs_urb*)info.si_addres
                  if (!ioctl_urb) {
                     printf("SIG_REAP gave NULL ioctl_urb");
                      continue;
                  }
                  UrbInfo *urbInfo = ioctl_urb->usercontext;
                  if (!urbInfo) {
                     printf("SIG_REAP gave NULL urbInfo");
                      continue;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code sample. It's hard to divine what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @red0ct I have updated the code sample

Comment: What are you doing with the `si_addr` member?  [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), `si_addr` is only used by `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGSEGV`, and `SIGBUS`, and those signals would be delivered to the faulting thread, not to your `sigwaitinfo()` call.  In other words, the value in `si_addr` is *meaningless* for the signals you appear to be catching.

Comment: I am using that signal address to reap URB's,I have attached continued part of code in my question

Comment: I am getting general protection error actually in this line UrbInfo *urbInfo = ioctl_urb->usercontext; when I am deferencing ioctl_urb. The problem is this is happening randomly,other signals are fine. Even in this case except the signal info.si_addr all other parameters are correct.This is evident after removing the offset in info.si_addr (0XFFFE00000000),I am able to successfully reap the signal

Comment: Where do `SIG_REAP` and `SIG_ISOC_CANCEL` come from?  A Google search for "Linux SIG_REAP" returns no direct use of any signal called `SIG_REAP` and the **ONLY** result for `SIG_ISOC_CANCEL` is this question itself.  Why do you think the address in `si_addr` is useful, given that the signal is not one of those listed by either POSIX or  Linux documentation as having a useful `si_addr` value?

Comment: Hard to debug this without knowing what info comes with  SIG_REAP, but maybe `ioctl_urb = (struct usbdevfs_urb*)info.si_addr` is an address from some process other than the receiver process.

Comment: @AndrewHenle As I said in the worKing scenario I am getting reap signal with proper address and I am able toreap URB as well. In problematic scenario  the problem is signal is reap its address is offset by 0XFFFE00000000

Comment: @MarkPlotnick submit_urb: Async fd:20 URB:102 i=0 ioctl_urb=0x12ab840
 After sigwaitinfo
 info.si_addr=0xfffe012ab840
 OK si_code -4 in SIG_REAP
 After ioctl urb =0xfffe012ab840   While submitting the address is proper,as you can see in first line,but the address returned from sigwaitinfo has offset

Comment: @MarkPlotnick In the working scenario submit_urb: Async fd:20 URB:102 i=0 ioctl_urb=0x12ab840 After sigwaitinfo info.si_addr=0x12ab840 OK si_code -4 in SIG_REAP After ioctl urb =0x012ab840

Comment: *As I said in the worKing scenario I am getting reap signal*  **What is "reap signal"?**  It's not standard, it's not in any Linux documentation I can find, and it's not of the standard `SIGXXX` form found in POSIX and Linux systems.  Without providing specifics of the non-standard `SIG_REAP`, this is not a complete example and doesn't meet the [requirements for a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry for mistake SIG_REAP in my case is SIGRTMIN   #define SIG_REAP SIGRTMIN
#define SIG_ISOC_CANCEL (SIGRTMIN + 1)

Comment: OK, so the sender is sometimes overwriting the high 32 bits of si_addr with `0xfffe`. siginfo is mostly a big union. `0xfffe` is 65534, which is often the "nobody" uid/gid. Check whether your signal sending code is writing into, for example, the gid member of a struct {uid_t, gid_t} member of the siginfo union.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for understanding my problem,the problematic signal UID is 65534

Comment: @MarkPlotnick In the working scenario signal atrributes are: Signal code=-4 Error code=0,Process pid=36685936 User ID=0 Signal number=34 Signal band=36685936 Signal status=0

Comment: @MarkPlotnick In the non working scenario:Signal code=-4 Error code=0,Process pid=36685936 User ID=65534 Signal number=34 Signal band=281466423462000 Signal status=0 So this I am printing out immediate after sigwaitinfo call the User ID and signal band is changing

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the code that sends the signal?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have uploaded the code that sends the signal

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have added code that sends signal as part of question

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Do u need any more information from my side

Comment: @srinicx I think there's enough info. I will have to look at kernel USB code that I am not familiar with. Might take a couple days.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Not a problem,today I checked 32 bit version of binary,there I am not finding offset,I am only finding it in 64 bit.Thanks for looking into

Comment: @srinicx Can you tell me which version of the kernel you're running that has the offset problem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick 4.15.0-51-generic  is the version.i think I am finding this issue in all Ubuntu 64 bit machines whichever I have checked

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Anything else you need from me?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Three fields of a signal are getting offset by 0XFFFE0. They are:User ID SIgnal band and si call addr . Working:Signal code=-4 Error code=0,Process pid=31455232 User ID=0 Signal number=34 Signal band=31455232 Signal status=0  si int=0 si ptr=(nil) si fd=0 si lower=(nil) si upper=(nil) si call addr=0x1dff800 si syscall=0 .                         Non working:Signal code=-4 Error code=0,Process pid=31455232 User ID=65534 Signal number=34 Signal band=281466418231296 Signal status=0  si int=0 si ptr=(nil) si fd=0 si lower=(nil) si upper=(nil) si call addr=0xfffe01dff800 si syscall=0

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If I set info.si_uid to 0 immediately after getting the signal ,all the parameters offset(0XFFFE) are removed

Comment: Are you running this in a new user namespace, such as a container? If so, the culprit may be [userns_fixup_signal_uid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/kernel/signal.c#L974), called by (a few levels down the call stack)  [async_completed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/drivers/usb/core/devio.c). The fixup function sets [si_uid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L129), overwriting part of the [si_addr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h#L139) field in the siginfo struct.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick when I have only single USB device I don't get these offset but if there is any other USB traffic I meant using headphones in browser to listen to audio  sometimes without headphone also I am getting this offset

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Where can I actually check if it is using the new userspace,the next signals have proper user ID of 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/how-to-determine-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker may cover the most common cases

Comment: When you see `User ID=65534`, how are you running your program? Are you doing `setuid(65534)` in your code or are you running a wrapper program that sets the uid to 65534 before running your program?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the issue is not happening in 32 bit,so is the issue with the kernel or my code?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick there is a wrapper program which has the uid nobody but if I set the user ID to something else  then also there is same offset of 65534

Comment: Is the wrapper program source code short enough to edit into your question, or can you give a link to it?

Comment: It works in 32-bit because the si_uid element in the big union in the siginfo struct is at bytes 4-7. On a 32-bit process, this won't clobber any part of si_addr. On a 64-bit process, it will clobber the high 4 bytes.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for your analysis. I checked today whether we are explicitly specifying User ID,but no luck

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Can I  change user ID 65534 to 0,will this be applicable in all linux distributions like Centos,Fedora.It is working in Ubuntu

Comment: Changing the uid to 0 will help a little - the kernel is still clobbering the high 32 bits of a 64-bit address - but it won't prevent the underlying problem. A better workaround is to check that the address you pass to the kernel is all zero in the upper 32 bits, and to refuse to continue if that's the case, and then zero out the upper 32 bits in the address sent by the signal. That's still just a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a signal such as SIGTRAP, as in Andrew's answer, instead of a RT signal?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I think while submitting to kernel address is fine, I haven't tried setting SIGTRAP

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Would the offset remain same in other distributions?

Comment: It might be present or not present based on kernel version. I haven't looked at anything except the version you run (4.15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `si_addr`.  It is available for only a limited number of signals, and those do not include any real-time signals.

[Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), `si_addr` is not applicable for signals other than `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGSEGV`, and `SIGBUS`. Linux also provides `si_addr` data for `SIGTRAP`:

> `SIGILL`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, and `SIGTRAP` fill in `si_addr` with the address of the fault.

No other signals provide a value for `si_addr`.

[The source code `linux/kernel/signal.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9221dced3069cc9ae2986ba1191b02dae560df28/kernel/signal.c) that fills in `si_addr` clearly shows that `si_addr` is not used for any signals other than those listed.

Note that per [the Linux `signal(7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> Real-time signals are distinguished by the following:
>
> 1. Multiple instances of real-time signals can be queued.  By
>             contrast, if multiple instances of a standard signal are
>             delivered while that signal is currently blocked, then only one
>             instance is queued.
> 2. If the signal is sent using [`sigqueue(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html), an accompanying value
>             (either an integer or a pointer) can be sent with the signal.  If
>             the receiving process establishes a handler for this signal using
>             the `SA_SIGINFO` flag to [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), then it can obtain this data
>             via the `si_value` field of the `siginfo_t` structure passed as the
>             second argument to the handler.  Furthermore, the `si_pid` and
>             `si_uid` fields of this structure can be used to obtain the PID and
>             real user ID of the process sending the signal.
>
> ...