# Is it possible to mount a squashfs file in google colab's VM?

Tags: ubuntu, google-colaboratory, squashfs

In a Google Colab Notebook, you can execute arbitrary bash commands by prefixing a line with `!` or starting a block with `%%shell`. You have significantly free permissions to do whatever you like in the Ubuntu 18.04 VM running the notebook, allowing you to download and install different programs.

I would like to create and mount a [squashfs](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/SquashFS-HOWTO/#creatingandusing) file, but mounting it is giving me an `operation not permitted`.

```sh
%%shell
apt-get update && apt-get install -y squashfs-tools
mksquashfs sample_data sample_data.sqsh
mount sample_data.sqsh /root/content/using_sqsh -t squashfs -o loop
```

Is there anything I can do to elevate my permissions? Or is mounting fundamentally not allowed on their infrastructure? And how do I check what, exactly, is not permitted to know whether it *could* be allowed?

Notes:

- I'm **NOT** trying to mount my Google Drive into the Colab Notebook.
- I don't want to `unsquashfs` the file. This is a theoretical question, not a practical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cat /proc/1/cgroup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/how-to-determine-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker) to confirm that the Colab VM is a docker container, docker containers are [not able to mount anything in unprivileged mode](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-use-mount-within-a-docker-container/77272) (the default), and [running in privileged mode would be a security issue](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/19/l/why-running-a-privileged-container-in-docker-is-a-bad-idea.html).

Thus, it is not possible to mount squashfs files (or anything else) in a Google Colab VM.