# How to check if process runs within a docker container (cgroup v2 linux host)

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

How to check if a process is running from within a Docker container? I'd like a method that works reliably, and that is future-proof.

This was already asked and answered at [How to determine if a process runs inside lxc/Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20010199/776208), however the answer is quite old, and it does not seem to work on a recent setup (Linux host with cgroups v2 enabled, Docker 20.10.x, kernel 5.10.x).

The top-rated answer (from the link above) suggests to check for the string `docker` in `/proc/1/cgroup`, however here's what I get:

```
# cat /proc/1/cgroup 
0::/
```

It seems to be due to the fact that [cgroups v2 is enabled on my host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471476/how-do-i-check-cgroup-v2-is-installed-on-my-machine) (it used to work with cgroups v1).

Another answer suggests to check for the existence of the file `/.dockerenv`. It works:

```
# test -e /.dockerenv && echo ok
ok
```

However a comment from a Docker's maintainer (dated from 2016) suggests NOT to rely on this file (emphasis mine):

> Originally, ".dockerenv" was for transmitting the environment
> variables of the container across the container boundary -- **I would
> not recommend relying on its existence** either (IIRC, that code you've
> linked to is the only reason it still exists).  There's likely
> something incriminatory inside /sys/fs/cgroup, but I haven't checked
> recently.
>
> -- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18355#issuecomment-220484748

So is there a better method than that? An answer from a Docker maintainer would be very much welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Did you find any solutions yet?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to check if a process runs **in** a docker container or **from within**, because those are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

If proc/1/cgroup is / you are basically guaranteed to be in a containerlike system (however note that if cgroupns=host that you'll get the host view in your container, so be sure to check that case too). In most linux OS systemd is the init system so /proc/1/cgroup will be /init.scope, so if it is not equal to /init.scope you are probably in a container of some sorts, and I believe this should work for cgroupns=private as well as cgroupns=host. Edit: tested in a --priviliged container with systemd as init, and cgroupns=private, and that will also show up as /init.scope unfortunately, however so just checking /proc/1/cgroup seems like it is only a best-effort guess. However I believe only the host-level /sys/fs/cgroup.procs is allowed to contain procs, any other container should have /sys/fs/cgroup.procs contain 0 entries when in a container. So it seems checking if /sys/fs/cgroup.procs is empty -> container, if it is not empty you can still be cgroupns=host, but in that case you can check if /proc/1/cgroup is in a containerpath. Edit2: According to https://systemd.io/CONTAINER_INTERFACE/: If you write software that wants to detect whether it is run in a container, please check /proc/1/environ and look for the container= environment variable. This does require being root.