# How to detect if the current script is running in a docker build?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

Suppose I have a `Dockerfile` which runs a script,

```
RUN ./myscript.sh
```

How could I write the `myscript.sh` so that it could detect if itself is launched by the `RUN` command during a `docker build`?

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# myscript.sh

if <What should I do here?>
then
  echo "I am in a docker build"
else
  echo "I am not in a docker build"
fi
```

Ideally, it should not require any changes in the `Dockerfile`, so that the caller of `myscript.sh` does not need specialized knowledge about `myscript.sh`.

Comment: Maybe add a specific ressource before calling the script that the script could detect, or call the script with an argument. Else I'm not sure that's easy

Comment: What would you do differently if you did determine you were in an image build?  Why can't you change the Dockerfile?

Comment: For example you are maintaining an installation script that could be used in either `docker build` or a physical machine, and you want to include some docker-specific optimization into the installation script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

# myscript.sh

isDocker(){
    local cgroup=/proc/1/cgroup
    test -f $cgroup && [[ "$(<$cgroup)" = *:cpuset:/docker/* ]]
}

isDockerBuildkit(){
    local cgroup=/proc/1/cgroup
    test -f $cgroup && [[ "$(<$cgroup)" = *:cpuset:/docker/buildkit/* ]]
}

isDockerContainer(){
    [ -e /.dockerenv ]
}

if isDockerBuildkit || (isDocker && ! isDockerContainer)
then
  echo "I am in a docker build"
else
  echo "I am not in a docker build"
fi
```

Comment: This is approximately the same trick as [How to determine if a process runs inside lxc/Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010199/how-to-determine-if-a-process-runs-inside-lxc-docker); but won't it also return true if you `docker run --rm the-image ./myscript.sh` as the main container command outside a build?

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right. I presume OP wanted to distinguish between `docker build` vs `non-docker build`.

Comment: It seems there is a difference between `docker build` and a Docker container when executing `cat /proc/1/cgroup`. 

 `/proc/1/cgroup` in a `docker build` contains something like `/docker/buildkit/xxxxxxxxx`. The `buildkit` string does not exist in a Docker container.

Comment: @YangBo for me, /proc/1/cgroup is exactly the same in both cases. Also /.dockerenv exists in build phase. I tested debian image. Which image are you using ?

Comment: It seems `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` or `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0` affect the cgroup 
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/

Comment: `.dockerenv` does not exist on buildkit

Comment: Indeed, and /proc/1/cgroup contains buildkit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238923/discussion-between-philippe-and-yang-bo).

Comment: `/.dockerenv` no longer exists on never docker versions, so it's no longer working

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime in on this, it seems I cannot comment (nor edit as the edit is two characters long... not enough for SO) on the accepted answer but it contains a typo.

the isDockerContainer should read

```
isDockerContainer(){
    [ -e /.dockerenv ]
}
```

which created a silent bug in our case.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, all I’m saying is the only way I could provide the corrected snippet is through this mean because of the reputation system that prevents any interaction even from legitimate accounts who try to provide some help 

Answer (score -4):

In your Dockerfile, you can try this to run the script

```
ADD myscript.sh .

RUN chmod +x myscript.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["myscript.sh"]
```